# remove path from VxDMP

Tags: veritas

Due to some temporary parallel cabling, VxVM 5.0 began to use two paths to a 3510 disk array:

```
# vxdmpadm getsubpaths
NAME         STATE[A]   PATH-TYPE[M] DMPNODENAME  ENCLR-NAME   CTLR   ATTRS
================================================================================
c2t40d2s2    ENABLED(A)   -          c2t40d2s2    sun35100     c2       -
c6t44d2s2    DISABLED     -          c2t40d2s2    sun35100     c6       -
```

On c6, the storage array is no longer present and we are going to attach an *other* storage array on that port - which may conflict with the current layout known by VxDMP.

How could I remove this path from Veritas' DMP control?

luxadm probe printout:

```
# luxadm probe
No Network Array enclosures found in /dev/es

Found Fibre Channel device(s):
  Node WWN:206000c0ff0b52a1  Device Type:Disk device
    Logical Path:/dev/rdsk/c2t40d2s2
    Logical Path:/dev/rdsk/c6t44d2s2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that dmpnodes (pseudo devices representing a collection of paths to a specific physical device) can not be deleted. Server restart cleans the dmpnode list.